# Google Sheet wrong date and time format for Timeline Graph

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, tasker

I import Tasker data source into a Google Sheet, but Timeline Graph does not work.

The format of the Date and Time is not understood.

The format of my data source is dd-MM-YYYY HH.mm
For example:
16-10-2020 00.40

But Google Sheet understands only dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss
16/10/2020 00:35:00

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFMbF.jpg)
(On the second picture, I modified the date to be 16/10/2020 00:35:00, and applied Date and Time format, so it display 16-10-2020 00.35, which serves no purpose other than confusing you)

I've tried to change the format of the date, but the only thing it does is:
Convert an already existing 16/10/2020 00:35:00 format
To 16-10-2020 00.40

I want the opposite.

I'm tired and kind of angry at Google Devs. I'm been searching for hours, and I find it crazy Google Sheet cannot understand this simple format.

Please any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the following formula to convert your values to dates

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A5="",,--REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A5,"-","/"),".",":")))
```

Depending on your locale you may have to change `,` to `;`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A5="";;--REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A5;"-";"/");"\.";":")))
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the conversion works. But why oh why does the Timeline Graph still gives me that error message???

Comment: Could there be a mistake with your graph? Have you tested it with real time dates (I mean without conversions)? If still in trouble please share a sheet and let me know. Don't worry. We'll figure it out. :)

Comment: Thank you it works now! https://imgur.com/a/twfkg62

Answer (score 1):

*An alternative to the solution already provided*

**Google Sheets Formulae**

You can use this formula in order to replace the `.` with `:` and drag it down in order for it to be applied to all the cells:

```
=REPLACE(A1,14,1,":")
```

This will result in a column with the date formatted in the way you want it.

**Google Apps Script**

You can also make use of Apps Script in order to replace all the `.` with `:` directly in the sheet.

```
// Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

function toDate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SS_ID").getSheetByName("SHEET_NAME");
  var range = ss.getRange(1,1,NO_OF_ROWS,1);
  var values = range.getValues();
  for (let i=1; i<values.length; i++)
    ss.getRange(i, 1).setValue(new Date(values[i-1][0].toString().replace(/\./g, ":")));
}
```

The script above also sets the value to be of type *date*.

#### Reference

- [REPLACE formula Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098247?hl=en);
- [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).